# Image of an element under a Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be Galois with Galois group $G$ and let $a\in K$. Suppose $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n$ are all the elements of $G$ and that $\sigma_1(a),...,\sigma_n(a)$ are all distinct. Then do we have that $K=F(a)$? Is this true because $G$ would then be uniquely determined by where it maps $a$? Is there a more explicit way to phrase this?

Further, if we were to assume all the images of $a$ under $G$ were distinct, why would this prevent us from having $K=F(a,b)$ for some other element $b\in K$?

Comment: Since $a$ has $n$ distinct Galois conjugates, its minimal polynomial must have degree $n$, so $[F(a):F] = n = |G| = [K:F]$, hence $K = F(a)$.